# shell validation checks syntax trouble

Tags: shell

syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
temp1.sh: line 40:`      fi' 
 line 40 is the 4 if statement with field3 check
I keep getting errors in this portion of the code mostly because i am not familar with shell and its my first script anyone please help me establish the ground rules for quoting variables and what not.

```
 #different validations
  if [[ ! -n "$field1" ]]; then
  ${FILESTATUS}=BAD
     # Stop inner loop
     break
  fi
  #somecheckonField2
      if [[ ! -n "$field2"  && ("$field2" != /$date_regex/) ]]; then
     ${FILESTATUS}=BAD
     # Stop inner loop
     break
  fi

      if [[ ! -n "$field3" && (("$field3" != "S") || ("$field3" != "E"))  ]]; th
  en
     ${FILESTATUS}=BAD
     # Stop inner loop
     break
  fi

      if [[ ! -n "$field4" || ((length("$field4") < 9 || (length("$field4") > 11))) ]]; then
     ${FILESTATUS}=BAD
     # Stop inner loop
     break
  fi
```

Comment: Is that `then` really split onto two lines in the source like that?

Comment: `${FILESTATUS}=BAD` isn't valid syntax. What do you want this to do? If you're trying to assign to the variable FILESTATUS, that's just `FILESTATUS=BAD`. If you're trying to assign to a variable named in the variable `FILESTATUS`, that's an indirect assignment, and there are other questions and answers talking about how to do it.

Comment: Also, don't nest your math context inside your `[[ ]]` context. Instead: `if [[ ! -n "$field4" ]] || (( ${#field4} < 9 || ${#field4} > 11 ))`

Comment: ...there isn't a `length` function, and functions aren't called as `funcname(argument)` in shell anyhow.

Comment: Also, regexes in bash don't use Perl/Ruby-esque `/foo/` syntax either.

Comment: ...perhaps you should actually start by going back and reading a bash syntax reference, rather than writing a mismash of pseudocode and trying to execute it? http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is a good place to start for a gentle introduction that won't teach bad habits (as some other guides do).

Comment: (also, all-caps names are reserved for environment variables and builtins; to avoid potential for namespace collisions, it would be better to call the variable in question `filestatus`).

Comment: (also, the operator to check whether something matches a regex is `=~`; `=` and `!=` check whether a string matches glob-style patterns, not regexes).